# Unable to grab success or failure i.e rc of long running Ansible task in a loop

Tags: performance, async-await, parallel-processing, ansible, return-code

Below is my code that takes about 20 minutes in all. The task takes about 1 minute and the loop runs 20 times so 20X1=20minutes. I want the playbook to fail if any task in `shell` module failed i.e `rc != 0`

```yaml
        - name: Check DB connection with DBPING
          shell: "java utils.dbping ORACLE_THIN {{ item | trim }}"
          with_items: "{{ db_conn_dets }}"
          delegate_to: localhost
```

Inorder, to speedup the tasks I decided to run them in parallel and then grab the success or failure of each tasks like below.

```yaml
        - name: Check DB connection with DBPING
          shell: "java utils.dbping ORACLE_THIN {{ item | trim }}"
          with_items: "{{ db_conn_dets }}"
          delegate_to: localhost
          async: 600
          poll: 0
          register: dbcheck

        - name: Result check
          async_status:
            jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
          register: _jobs
          until: _jobs.finished
          delay: 10
          retries: 20
          with_items: "{{ dbcheck.results }}"
```

Now !! The task `Check DB connection with DBPING` completes in less than a minute for the entire loop. However, the problem is that ALL the task `Result check` fails even if the  task `Check DB connection with DBPING` **WOULD EVENTUALLY SUCCEED** i.e `rc=0`

Below is one sample failing task `Result check` when it should have been successful

```
 failed: [remotehost] (item={'_ansible_parsed': True, '_ansible_item_result': True, '_ansible_no_log': False, u'ansible_job_id': u'234197058177.18294', '_ansible_delegated_vars': {'ansible_delegated_host': u'localhost', 'ansible_host': u'localhost'}, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'failed': False, u'finished': 0, u'results_file': u'/home/ansbladm/.ansible_async/234197058177.18294', 'item': u'dbuser mypass dbhost:1521:mysid', '_ansible_ignore_errors': None}) => {
     "ansible_job_id": "234197058177.18294", 
     "attempts": 1, 
     "changed": false, 
     "finished": 1, 
     "invocation": {
         "module_args": {
             "jid": "234197058177.18294", 
             "mode": "status"
         }
     }, 
     "item": {
         "ansible_job_id": "234197058177.18294", 
         "changed": true, 
         "failed": false, 
         "finished": 0, 
         "item": "dbuser mypass dbhost:1521:mysid", 
         "results_file": "/home/ansbladm/.ansible_async/234197058177.18294", 
         "started": 1
     }, 
     "msg": "could not find job", 
     "started": 1
 }
```

Can you please let me know what is the issue with my task `Result check` and how can i make sure it keeps trying till the task `Check DB connection with DBPING` completes and thereby reports success or failure upon the `.rc` of  `shell` module?

It will also be great if i could get the the `debug` module to print all failed `shell` tasks of `Check DB connection with DBPING`.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a partial answer to the set of queries i had. I will accept a complete answer if it comes in the future.

Adding           `delegate_to: localhost` to task `Result check` inoder to resolve the behavior.

I'm however still waiting for the code to show all failed tasks in the `debug`.